# How to find the origin of some invasive html?

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been working on the site https://founderspledge.com/ and just noticed that if you go to the main page, and open the Chrome console to view the source, there's an element that I certainly didn't put there:

```
<div class="pub_300x250 pub_300x250m pub_728x90 text-ad textAd
 text_ad text_ads text-ads text-ad-links" style="position: absolute;">.</div>
```

It also doesn't show up when I run the site's code in localhost, or when I load the page source separately using Chrome's 'View Source' option.

I Googled the div's class list, and the top few hits were from anti-ad blocker software (eg https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock), which doesn't seem malign, but doesn't explain why it would be on this site.

So

1) How can I get rid of this element?

2) How might it have got there?

3) Does it imply there's a hole in the site's security?

Comment: It's probably been dynamically injected by one of your javascript files. try disabling each script in turn to find out which one is adding it. It doesn't imply that there is any security hole - injected elements are common.

Comment: I found that facebook pixel tracking was causing the issue. Question now is how to fix it

Comment: Can I ask how you isolated it? I was going through an insanely inefficient process of deleting groups of script elements and redeploying the whole app to our staging site!

Comment: @Arepo to avoid that you can use Segment or Google Tag Manager, to enable or disable integrations with a single click.

Comment: I paused the facebook tracking code within tag manager, which seems to of fixed the issue. FWIW, i'm in firefox and can see the issue appearing on my sites and your https://founderspledge.com/ as well as in chrome.
I've asked on the facebook ad support forum - i'll post any solution suggested

Comment: Thanks! Could you link to the thread in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Facebook have acknowledged this as a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/336662116810282/?hc_location=ufi

I'm so glad to find this issue - have been tearing my hair out to work out the same exact thing! I found it's coming from fbevents.js (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js) version 2.8.7 - you can clearly see the code that adds the div in. It seems like this is something that has happened very recently? But likewise, I couldn't find anything other than references to anti adblocking scripts which had me concerned!